# How to use JavaScript replace an inline html element preceded and followed by text with another html element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, removechild

I know, this seems like a really simple, straightforward question but bear with me for a minute.

Lets say we have a HTML document that looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Awesome Example.</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>World History is fascinating but can also be overwhelming because of its 
sheer magnitude. Every historian brings their own <span class="blank-it">lens</span>
to historical interpretation so one must not only know the historical events but 
also use <span class="blank-it">reasoning</span> skills to determine when a 
historian's perspective is distorting the actual historical record.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now lets say we want to replace each occurrence of `<span class="blank-it">` and replace it with another element and the original element's innerHTML. So the end result would be something like:

```
<input type="text" id="lens115">
<input type="text" id="reasoning118">
```

The issue is the element being inline with the text. I had come up with some code that looks something like this:

```
// Get the element to be replaced
let blankhtml = document.getElementByClassNames("blank-it");
// Get the text we'll use as the ID of our new element
let blanktext = document.getElementByClassNames("blank-it").innerHTML;
// Create a variable to hold input text box code
let inputtext = '<input type="text" id="' . blanktext . '" class="blank-input">';
// Prepend the input box before the blankhtml element
// Remove the old element.
```

And this is where I get stuck. Because it seems that whether I use `insertBefore` or `removeChild` it wants me to specify the parent element. But how can I know this? In the above example it is a simple `<p>` element but what if the code looked something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Something Goes Here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a <span class="important-text"><span class="blank-it">an important fact.</span><span>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally one should only have a single span in this instance, but we are talking about user entered content, so I can't guarantee there won't be a situation like this.

I'm sure this is still a fairly simple problem to resolve, just slightly more complicated than telling me to use replaceChild, etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's `getElementsByClassName` with an `s` and it returns a collection not a single element

Comment: Maybe I didn't quite understand the problem, but have you considered using `outerHTML` to replace the element? You can set the outerHTML of your span with your input HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using outerHTML to replace the element, instead of using insertBefore/removeChild?

If I understood correctly, you want to replace your span with an input, correct?

See if the snippet below can help you out:

```js
// Get elements to be replaced
let blankElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("blank-it"));

blankElements.forEach(blankElement => {
  // Get the text we'll use as the ID of our new element
  let blanktext = blankElement.innerHTML;
  // Create a variable to hold input text box code
  let inputtext = '<input type="text" id="' + blanktext + '" class="blank-input">';
  blankElement.outerHTML = inputtext;
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Awesome Example.</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>World History is fascinating but can also be overwhelming because of its 
sheer magnitude. Every historian brings their own <span class="blank-it">lens</span>
to historical interpretation so one must not only know the historical events but 
also use <span class="blank-it">reasoning</span> skills to determine when a 
historian's perspective is distorting the actual historical record.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough starter for you that replaces each of those spans with an input that has the span's innerHTML as value.

To start with you need to loop over the collection, create a new element to replace each instance with and then use `parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, existingChild)`

You can dress up the attributes/classes of the new element with whatever you need yourself

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".blank-it").forEach(el => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');    
    input.value = el.innerHTML;
    input.classList.add('blank-input');
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(input, el);
});
```

```css
.blank-input{color:red}
```

```html
<p>World History is fascinating but can also be overwhelming because of its 
sheer magnitude. Every historian brings their own <span class="blank-it">lens</span>
to historical interpretation so one must not only know the historical events but 
also use <span class="blank-it">reasoning</span> skills to determine when a 
historian's perspective is distorting the actual historical record.</p>
```